# what's the cause of Proxy Error in my cxf client?

Tags: java, web-services, proxy, cxf

When I call a webservice within cxf client from my local computer everything is ok but when I call the webservice on server the webservice displays the message below:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: IOException invoking https://service.myorg.com/MyService/Service.svc: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). )"
```

Comment: Are you running your webservice behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes the proxy address of our company is proxy.myorg.com and I try something like this but the same problem exists:    Properties props= new Properties(System.getProperties());
   props.put("http.proxySet", "true");
   props.put("http.proxyHost", "172.1.1.1");
   props.put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
   props.put("https.proxySet", "true");
   props.put("https.proxyHost", "172.1.1.1");
   props.put("https.proxyPort", "8080");
   Properties newprops = new Properties(props);
   System.setProperties(newprops);